# How to modified final position LineRenderer in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using `LineRenderer` in a project with **Unity+Vuforia** for AR. The idea is to create MindMap with nodes and its conexions (this with LineRenderer). I've already done this. But I can't to do that the child node change final position when this is dragged.

I've tried to disable the check `Use World Space`, and it's working with the parent node because when I drag it the Lines, it moves also.

For example, if I move Node 1, everything moves because it's parent, but if I move node 2, the LineRenderer 2 doesn't follow. This is what I don't want to happen.

[image: Draw nodes]

This is my code to **draw** the LineRenderer

```
public class DrawLineScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;

    public void DrawLine(GameObject parent, GameObject child){
        if(parent.name != "Spawner"){
            GameObject newLineGen = Instantiate(obj);   
            newLineGen.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find(parent.name).transform);
            LineRenderer line = newLineGen.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

            line.name = "Line " + child.name;

            line.positionCount = 2;
            line.SetPosition(0, parent.transform.position);
            line.SetPosition(1, child.transform.position); 
        }   
    }
}
```

This is my code to **drag** nodes

```
public class DragScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 mOffset;
    private float mZCoord;

    public GameObject nodo;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
        mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - GetMouseAsWorldPoint();
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseAsWorldPoint()
    {
        // Pixel coordinates of mouse (x,y)
        Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;

        // z coordinate of game object on screen
        mousePoint.z = mZCoord;

        // Convert it to world points
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        transform.position = GetMouseAsWorldPoint() + mOffset;
    } 
}
```

I supposed that use `Update()` with a Event that permit to update the final position of the LineRenderer associated with the child node. I tried to put to GameObject LineRenderer the next script:

```
public class UpdateLineScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    private Vector3 beginPosOffset;
    private Vector3 endPosOffset;   
    private Transform dentiny;
    private LineRenderer line;

    void Start() 
    {
        line = obj.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        Vector3[] pos = new Vector3[line.positionCount];
        line.GetPositions(pos);

        //Get offset
        beginPosOffset = transform.position - pos[0];
        endPosOffset = transform.position - pos[1];
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newBeginPos = transform.position + beginPosOffset;
        Vector3 newEndPos = transform.position + endPosOffset;

        //Apppy new position with offset
        line.SetPosition(0, newBeginPos);
        line.SetPosition(1, newEndPos);
    }
}
```

But the lines appear in anywhere.

[image: Update LineRenderer]

Repository github with the project (branch develop):[MindMap Repository](https://github.com/emicalvacho/ProtoMindMapAR/tree/develop)

Comment: *`This is my code to drag the LineRenderer`* That isn't the code that drags it, that's the code that spawns sets the initial positions. Where's the code that actually deals with user input.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm sorry I already update the question. What do you mean by user input code?

Comment: The code you've shown is one-and-done. There's no "dragging" or "repositioning" of the objects in the code you've included so far.

Comment: @Draco18s The question is updated

Comment: Ok, so your code updates *both* ends of the script based on the movement of *one* of the spheres (and you still haven't shown the code that moves the spheres). There are two spheres for each line. They can move independently. Which one gets to move both ends of the line?

Comment: @Draco18s The one that can always move the end of the line is the one that has the origin, that is to say the father thanks to the fact that he deactivates the ```Use World Space``` option of the LineRenderer.

Comment: Alright, then, finish the sentence: 
"When you move the child sphere, _______________ happens, and that keeps the line correct."

Comment: @Draco18s "When you move the child sphere, LineRenderer doesn't follow it, and that keeps the line right."

Comment: @Draco18s Read the question carefully

Comment: Read my comments carefully. You want a certain behavior to happen and currently do not have any code to make that behavior happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply leave it at `Use World Space` and put this component on the same object as the `LineRenderer`:

```
public class UpdateLineScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] LineRenderer line;

    private Transform _parentTransform;
    private Transform _childTransform;

    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[2];

    public void Initialize (Transform parentTransform, Transform childTransform, string newName)
    {
        name = newName;

        if(!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        _parentTransform = parentTransform;
        _childTransform = childTransform;

        line.positionCount = 2;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        positions[0] = parentTransform.position;
        positions[1] = childTransform.position; 

        line.SetPositions(positions);
    }
}
```

Then wherever you spawn the new line you `Initialize` it with the two `Transform` references. From there on it simply can get the according positions itself

```
public class DrawLineScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Make this directly of type UpdateLineRenderer
    // this way you don't need GetComponent later
    public UpdateLineScript prefab;

    public void DrawLine(GameObject parent, GameObject child)
    {
        if(parent.name == "Spawner") return;

        var newLine = Instantiate(prefab, parent.transform);   

        // Here you pass in all required information
        newLine.Initialize(parent.transform, child.transform, "Line " + child.name);
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't matter how you move the nodes. The first script simply constantly copies the absolute world positions of both node objects.

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*